# Backbone.js and navigation

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Since backbone does not have its way of doing most things, i am confused on a lot of stuff. One of that things is the right way to navigate through my app.

I realize that a BB Router has a '.navigate' method which can be used to push urls and trigger routes. Now since my app has more than 1 router, i am not sure what the difference is between calling '.navigate' on the one or other router.

This are my Routers

```
new Etaxi.Routers.System()
new Etaxi.Routers.Header()
new Etaxi.Routers.Videos()
new Etaxi.Routers.News()
```

Now i could do

```
router = Etaxi.Routers.System()
// or i could do
router = Etaxi.Routers.Header()

router.navigate(url)
```

Is there any difference which router i use for my global app navigation? This seems weird to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference in which router you call. In fact, I recommend not calling a specific router, when you have multiple routers. Or, for that matter, don't bother calling a router at all. If you look at the source code for router's `navigate` method, you'll see that it does nothing more than pass through to `Backbone.history.navigate`. So just call that directly:

`Backbone.history.navigate(url)`

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-114

I use multiple routers in nearly all of my apps, and this is how I call the `navigate` method. It works great, and avoids the confusion of which router to call.